# Parse form data through socket.io and retrieve data

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to parse form data through a host that will go out to clients in a second-screen style web app however I'm struggling to get the form data, particularly nameTheBet from the host and to the clients.

What am I missing? Code below:

HTML Block

```
<script id="create-game-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="createGameWrapper">
        <div id="betSummary">
            <div class="info">
                <span class="nameTheBet"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info">Open this site on your mobile device:</div>

        <div id="gameURL" class="infoBig">Error!</div>
            <div class="info">Then click <strong>JOIN</strong> and <br/> enter the following Game ID:</div>
            <div id="spanNewGameCode" class="gameId">Error!</div>
        <div id="playersWaiting"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Storing the data

```
onCreateClick: function () {

IO.socket.emit('hostCreateNewGame');

var data = {
    gameId : +($('#inputGameId').val()),
    placeBet : +($('#inputPlaceBet').val()),
    nameTheBet : $('#inputNameTheBet').val(),
    playerName : $('#inputPlayerName').val() || 'anon'
};
$('#betSummary')
    .append('<p/>')
    .text(data.nameTheBet);

IO.socket.emit('nameTheBet', data);

// Set the appropriate properties for the current player.
App.myRole = 'Host';
App.Host.myBet = data.nameTheBet;
},
```

Retrieving

```
function nameTheBet(data) {

io.sockets.in(data.gameId).emit('nameTheBet', data);
}
```

Comment: are you listening for an event called 'nameTheBet' on the client as well?  And are you sure the 'nameTheBet' event is getting emitted properly from the server?

Comment: I think this is where it's failing. What am I missing to make sure the client is listening for the event and how do I debug from the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote my functions from scratch and debugged at each step parsing from the client to the server then emitting back to the client. The emit from the server back to the client was the issue.

Storing the data

```
onCreateClick: function () {

    var data = {
        nameTheBet : $('#inputNameTheBet').val() || 'anon',
        playerName : $('#inputPlayerName').val() || 'anon'
    };

    IO.socket.emit('hostCreateNewGame', data);

    App.myRole = 'Player';
    App.Player.myBet = data.nameTheBet;
},
```

Server side

```
function hostCreateNewGame(data) {
    // Create a unique Socket.IO Room
    var thisGameId = ( Math.random() * 100000 ) | 0;
    var thisBet = data.nameTheBet

    this.emit('newGameCreated', {gameId: thisGameId, mySocketId: this.id, nameTheBet: thisBet});

    this.join(thisGameId.toString());
}
```

This does something....

```
onNewGameCreated : function(data) {
    App.Host.gameInit(data);
    App[App.myRole].setTheBet(data);
    console.log(data.nameTheBet);
},
```

Appending the HTML block

```
setTheBet : function(data) {
    $('#betSummary')
        .append('<p/>')
        .text(data.nameTheBet);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you emit data, it needs to be wrapped within an on connection function, which will look like:

```
IO.on('connection', function(socket){
  //your code here
  socket.emit('nameTheBet', data);
});
```

*edit In both places you are emitting but I don't see anywhere where you are listening with a `socket.on('nameTheBet')`

Comment: Sorry should have added that the emit is already nested within an on connection function. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ah yeah all the connections are working because I can get the player name back, just not any of the other values. I'm thinking it must be in the storing function?

Comment: Right before you emit your data in the storing function, when you console.log(data) does it produce the outcome you're expecting?

Comment: Yep, `Object {gameId: NaN, placeBet: NaN, nameTheBet: "GHGHGHG", playerName: "FDFDFDFD"}`

Comment: In that case, wouldn't your error be in the io.sockets.in(data.gameId) since that is not a number?

Comment: Sorry my edit time expired. Meant to add; ignore gameID and placeBet, they're both redundant and I've commented out for now. Still no good!